# How can I watch HD Amazon videos on Logitech Revue?

Tags: google-tv, logitech-revue, amazon-video

I'm running the latest updates for my Logitech Revue (according to the check for updates screen), but when I go to the Amazon Instant Video app, it just redirects me to Chrome.  Amazon doesn't support HD in the browser, so I can only watch SD videos.

When I try to play HD videos, Amazon says, I must use a supported device, which the Logitech Revue is, and that I must register it.  Its instructions to register it say to open the "Amazon Video" app on the device, then go to "register device".  As mentioned, my app (named "Amazon Instant Video") just redirects to Chrome.

I called Amazon, and they said it sounds like I'm running "google tv version 1.0".  Since my "firmware" says 3.2 and i apparently have the latest updates, I'd guess that I'm not.  Amazon support says only Google tv v2.0 has the application w/ HD.

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: It sounds like the Amazon rep just didn't know what they were talking about. AFAIK the app (which was released late last month) is only compatible with LG televisions, and not any of the currently existing set-top boxes (see [the Google+ announcement](https://plus.google.com/u/0/106322104148750976656/posts/6nUE6tbbpMs)). I believe that getting the HD content on your Revue is simply not possible at the moment since it's going through the browser, not an actual app.

Comment: Thanks, at least I can take comfort in knowing that there are many other Logitech Revue owners complaining on that thread. I'll keep an eye out for a future release of their app.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem with the Google TV OS, not the device's firmware.

There was a Google TV update that supposedly came down the stream quite some time ago, but my Logitech Revue never got it.  It was SUPPOSED to have given Amazon Instant an ACTUAL app instead of the link to Chrome which is currently on the device.  Since Logitech is no longer supporting the device, I don't count on ever getting that update, or any updates.

What annoys me about this issue, though, is that I USED to get HD through Chrome on my Revue. I actually bought an HD season pass for Walking Dead at the beginning of the season, and watched the first half in HD.  I stumbled across the inability to watch HD content only a couple weeks ago. There must have been a software update on Amazon's end that created this new incompatibility, and since the Revue isn't getting any more updates, it will continue losing functionality like this.

I am going to try watching Walking Dead via PlayOn to see if it makes any sort of difference.  Though, that only runs through Chrome, also.  It does not have its own app on the Revue, even though it does on a lot of other devices and platforms.

It's only a matter of time before I replace my Revue with a Roku or something now.